# Symfony Process Component mysqldump gzip

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to figure out how to add pipe with gzip compression to the mysqldump command using Symfony Process Component. What I have, and what doesn't seem to work is:

```
$date = Carbon::now();

$fileName = $date->format('Y-m-d_H-i-s').'.sql';

$command = [
    $this->mysqldumpPath,
    '--add-drop-table',
    '--skip-comments',
    '--default-character-set=utf8mb4',
    $this->ignoreTables(),
    '--user='.$this->dbConfig['username'],
    '--password='.$this->dbConfig['password'],
    $this->dbConfig['database'],
];

if ($this->compress) {
    $command[] = '| gzip -9';
    $fileName = $fileName.'.gz';
}

$file = $this->backupPath($fileName);

$process = new Process(array_merge(
    $command,
    ['--result-file='.$file]
));

$process->run();
```

The error I'm getting is

> mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "| gzip -9"

The `ignoreTables()` method

```
private function ignoreTables(): ?string
{
    if (empty($this->ignoreTables)) {
        return null;
    }

    return collect($this->ignoreTables)->map(
        fn(string $table) => sprintf(
            '--ignore-table=%s.%s',
            $this->dbConfig['database'],
            $table
        )
    )->implode(' ');
}
```

Any idea how I can pass piped gzip flag to the command?

Comment: I haven't found any way to do this either - maybe it's better to write that file, and compress it in a second process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still build your command as a string and run it in a shell with [`Process::fromShellCommandline`](https://github.com/symfony/process/blob/f3957bcc7ec492baf22812c48e7cccf152491770/Process.php#L168).

I think your command won't work as written, though, so I'm making the changes I think are necessary (you can also clean this up and not use arrays to build the command).

Main:

```
$date = Carbon::now();
$fileName = $date->format('Y-m-d_H-i-s').'.sql';
$file = $this->backupPath($fileName);

$command = [
    $this->mysqldumpPath,
    '--add-drop-table',
    '--skip-comments',
    '--default-character-set=utf8mb4',
    '--user="${:USER}"',
    '--password="${:PASSWORD}"',
    '"${:DATABASE}"',
];
$command = array_merge($command, $this->getIgnoredTablesArguments());

if ($this->compress) {
    $command[] = ' | gzip -9 > "${:OUTPUT_FILE}"';
    $file .= '.gz';
} else {
    $command[] = '--result-file="${:OUTPUT_FILE}"';
}

$process = Process::fromShellCommandline(implode(' ', $command));

$parameters = [
    'USER' => $this->dbConfig['username'],
    'PASSWORD' => $this->dbConfig['password'],
    'DATABASE' => $this->dbConfig['database'],
    'OUTPUT_FILE' => $file,
];
$parameters = array_merge($parameters, $this->getIgnoredTablesParameters());

$process->run(null, $parameters);
```

Helper methods:

```
private function ignoreTables(): array
{
    return collect($this->ignoreTables)->map(
        fn(string $table) => sprintf(
            '%s.%s',
            $this->dbConfig['database'],
            $table
        )
    );
}

private function getIgnoredTablesArguments(): array
{
    $arguments = [];
    foreach ($this->ignoreTables as $k => $v) {
        $argName = sprintf('${:IGNORE_%s}', $k);
        $arguments[] = sprintf('--ignore-table="%s"', $argName);
    }
    return $arguments;
}

private function getIgnoredTablesParameters(): array
{
    $envs = [];
    foreach ($this->ignoreTables() as $k => $v) {
        $argName = sprintf('IGNORE_%s', $k);
        $envs = array_merge($envs, [$argName => $v]);
    }
    return $envs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @msg - however this way I have to deal with escaping and portability myself as opposed to using array format. Not ideal, but a workaround should there really be no other option.

Comment: It is struggling with placeholders and `| gzip -9` - keeps on telling me `mysqldump: unknown option '-9'.` and when I remove `-9` then it tells me that `| gzip` table doesn't exists. Looks like the only way to make it work is to pass the statement with all vars replaced - shame, but I can't see it work any other way.

Comment: Thanks. It did work except for `ignoreTables()` - I've updated the ticket to show the implementation of this method.